# Поведение match в JavaScript

Tags: регулярные-выражения, match, javascript

Все привет. Снова немного о регулярных выражениях в JS.
Я ожидаю, что код:

```
'aabb'.match(/a.*b/g);
```

Вернет мне массив:

```
['aab', 'aabb', 'ab', 'abb'];
```

Почему он возвращает массив только с одним элементом?

```
['aabb']
```

Разве `str.match(RegExp);` не должен возвращать массив всех совпадений по регулярному выражению?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@Алексей Данчин](/users/11565/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD)](/users/11565/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD), проблема в том, что вы не понимаете значение используемого вами квантификатора.

```
.* - найти последовательность из любых символов, кроме переноса строки, максимальной длины в промежутке от нуля, до бесконечности.
```

Ключевое здесь **последовательность максимальной длины**. aabb - как раз подходит под это определение.

Comment: Спасибо. Уловил. А как сделать не максимальной, а любой?

Comment: @Алексей Данчин, смотря что вы хотите сделать.  
Если сгенерировать такой массив с помощью match, то я не вижу способов, как это сделать одной универсальной регуляркой.  
А вообще, можно сделать либо максимальной, либо минимальной, либо конкретной длины. Не могу понять, как система должна угадывать "любую" длину.